# Error on registration page in ASP.NET Core with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the *Building Your First ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC Application with Visual Studio 2017* Pluralsight course made by Gill Cleeren.

I have opened the last chapter which contains the full Bethany's Pie Shop application.

In the next step, I have build the solution, typed update-database in Package Manager Console and run the app.

The app is running and it works till I try to register a username.

I don't know exactly what is the error but the data is not registering in the AspNetUsers table.

Below you may find the **AccountController.cs** file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using BethanysPieShop.ViewModels;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace BethanysPieShop.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(loginViewModel);

            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginViewModel.UserName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginViewModel.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User name/password not found");
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }

        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View(new LoginViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = loginViewModel.UserName };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, loginViewModel.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know whether you need other files.

Do you have any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

**LE**: It seems that I can retrieve information from database. So, I think the issue might be from code. I will also post below the **Startup.cs** file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using BethanysPieShop.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace BethanysPieShop
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

            //services.AddTransient<IPieRepository, MockPieRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IPieRepository, PieRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IFeedbackRepository, FeedbackRepository>();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**LE2**: I have uploaded the project on the following link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/22127bc342c3c969cf2ccdd208506b7120200122210123/68db42

Comment: Include your stack trace.

Comment: If there's no error, but the AspNetUsers table isn't being modified, there's a good chance that your connection-string is pointing to a database that is different from the one you're looking at.

Comment: After I click register I get a breakpoint on the line if (ModelState.IsValid) in Register method. You can see that by accessing the following link to the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/qzG4NZQ. Kirk, when I updated the database, the tables were created and it also contains data on some tables. I have verified and noticed that the connection string is pointing to the local DB. LinkedListT, can you please tell me how can I include my stack trace? Thank you.